# Client #2 in Sega Rally 2 locks up at race start in multiplayer

Tags: arcade, sega-rally-2

We have an european Sega Rally 2 arcade machine with dual consoles (two racing seats, not the complete car version, named "twin"). Both consoles work as they should in single player, and they both show the racing action from the other client. However, when launching a multiplayer game, client #2 (of 2) locks up at the start (during the countdown) or right after the countdown has finished.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what can be the error? Is it possible the link cable is borked, or that the master/slave setup should be switched around? (it's currently the slave that locks up).

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more experimenting, switching which console was master/slave solved the problem for now. The console that locked up also presents with a memory error on IC17 on self testing, which might be the reason why it locks up under certain conditions.